# SQL: Pulling information based on two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Please bear with me, this is a little difficult to explain:
Trying to find a way to pull names that contains "Op" in "Type" column, but the "Code" values must be unique with "Type"

Such as: (Using the first 3 rows below)

Do not pull first or second row, because "SPX" is related to both "Com" and "Op", but pull row #3 because "VPA" only has "Op" in column "Type". So the values under "code" column cannot be in both "Op" and "Com" under type for the each account.

**Input"**

```
Name    Type    Code
John    Com     SPX
John    Op      SPX
John    Op      VPA
John    Op      SPX
Matt    Op      SPX
Matt    Op      SPX
Jane    Com     SPX
Jane    Com     SPR
Jack    Op      SPR
Jack    Op      SPX
Jack    Com     SPR
```

**Output:**

```
Name    Type    Code
John    Op      VPA
Matt    Op      SPX
Matt    Op      SPX
Jack    Op      SPX
```

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: hint `not exists`

Comment: just updated my answer based on your last update..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  `NOT EXISTS`

```
select * 
from
mytable t1
where not exists
(
select 1 from mytable t2
where t2.type = 'com'
and t2.name = t1.name   -- if the name exists with a com type then exclude
)
```